# How to use JavaScript remove numbers and letters after a character from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to use Javascript to remove the dash and everything after in an array of product ids. But not if the dash is in the middle of the product id.  For example product ids:

```
["630932-8", "640993-8", "1951-83044226", "641452-10", "1924-57044108", "630695-8 DD/F", "641058-8", "630932-20", "630695-14 DD/F", "630695-22 D/DD", "630695-12 C/D", "661049-6", "661050-4", "630692-8 C/D", "630513-38 G", "630513-36 F", "630655-36 DD", "630695-8 C/D", "661049-4", "630695-16 C/D"]
```

This is for use within a tag management system and need the to drop everything after the "-" so it would be

```
["630932", "640993", "1951-83044226", "641452", "1924-57044108", "630695", "641058", "630932", "630695", "630695", "630695", "661049", "661050", "630692", "630513", "630513", "630655", "630695", "661049", "630695"]
```

There will be some that have will have 4 digits then the dash and those need to stay. The Product ids are currently populated in a datalayer with the "-" they are referenced by utag.data.product_skus

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` and `split()`.

- Use `map()` on the array.
- `split()` all the strings by `-`.
- Check if first part of result of `split()` has length `4` then return the original string.
- Otherwise return the first part of the result obtained from `split()`

```js
let arr = ["630932-8", "640993-8", "1951-83044226", "641452-10", "1924-57044108", "630695-8 DD/F", "641058-8", "630932-20", "630695-14 DD/F", "630695-22 D/DD", "630695-12 C/D", "661049-6", "661050-4", "630692-8 C/D", "630513-38 G", "630513-36 F", "630655-36 DD", "630695-8 C/D", "661049-4", "630695-16 C/D"]


let res = arr.map(x => {
  let parts = x.split('-');
  return parts[0].length === 4 ? x : parts[0];
  
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace unwanted parts.

```js
function remove(s) {
    return s.replace(/^(\d{5,})-.*$/, '$1');
}

var array = ["630932-8", "640993-8", "1951-83044226", "641452-10", "1924-57044108", "630695-8 DD/F", "641058-8", "630932-20", "630695-14 DD/F", "630695-22 D/DD", "630695-12 C/D", "661049-6", "661050-4", "630692-8 C/D", "630513-38 G", "630513-36 F", "630655-36 DD", "630695-8 C/D", "661049-4", "630695-16 C/D"];

console.log(array.map(remove));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `split`, with a regex to check the 4-digit case:

```js
const data = ["630932-8", "640993-8", "1951-83044226", "641452-10", "1924-57044108", "630695-8 DD/F", "641058-8", "630932-20", "630695-14 DD/F", "630695-22 D/DD", "630695-12 C/D", "661049-6", "661050-4", "630692-8 C/D", "630513-38 G", "630513-36 F", "630655-36 DD", "630695-8 C/D", "661049-4", "630695-16 C/D"];
const res = data.map(s => /^\d{4}-/.test(s) ? s : s.split("-")[0]);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed like this

```js
var data = ["630932-8", "640993-8", "1951-83044226", "641452-10", "1924-57044108", "630695-8 DD/F", "641058-8", "630932-20", "630695-14 DD/F", "630695-22 D/DD", "630695-12 C/D", "661049-6", "661050-4", "630692-8 C/D", "630513-38 G", "630513-36 F", "630655-36 DD", "630695-8 C/D", "661049-4", "630695-16 C/D"];

var needed_data = [];
data.map(function(val) {
  var matches = val.match(/^([0-9]{5,})-.*/);
  if(matches) {
    needed_data.push(matches[1])
  } else  {
    var submatches = val.match(/(^[0-9]{4})-([0-9]*)/);
    if(submatches[1] && submatches[2]) {
      needed_data.push(val)
    }
  }
});

console.log(needed_data);
```